# Could not launch Intent within 45 seconds - robotium

Tags: android, robotium, ui-testing

I'm facing a big problem which I've been trying to solve for a few days. I  am trying to run a test using robotium but when I call `getActivity()` on the setup method, a `RuntimeException` exception is thrown.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000
>   cmp=com.company.app/.SplashActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the
>   main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time?
>   There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the
>   screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the
>   threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was
>   idle before your activity launch request was 1463908619275 and now the
>   last time the queue went idle was: 1463908619275. If these numbers are
>   the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.

I'm using robotium 5.4.4

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which reproduces the exact error message.